# How to parse XML in Postgres 11 and in Postgres 9.1.2

Tags: xml, postgresql, xml-parsing, postgresql-11

In Postgres 9.1.2 script below produces proper results:

```
1.34
5.56
```

In Postgres 11 it produces wrong results:

```
null
null
```

How to make it also to work in newer versions on Postgres ?

```
create temp table t(x xml, nsa text[][]) on commit drop;
insert into t values(
    '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.053.001.02">
  <BkToCstmrStmt>
    <Stmt>
      <Ntry>
        <Amt Ccy="EUR">1.34</Amt>
      </Ntry>
      <Ntry>
        <Amt Ccy="EUR">5.56</Amt>
      </Ntry>
    </Stmt>
  </BkToCstmrStmt>
</Document> '::xml,
    ARRAY[ARRAY['ns','urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.053.001.02']]);

    SELECT 
    (xpath('Amt/text()', x,nsa))[1]::text::numeric AS tasusumma
    FROM (
        SELECT unnest(xpath('/ns:Document/ns:BkToCstmrStmt/ns:Stmt/ns:Ntry', x,nsa)) as x,
        nsa
        FROM t
    ) Ntry
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is enough to qualify `Amt` with its namespace alias:

```
SELECT (xpath('ns:Amt/text()', x, nsa))[1]::text::numeric AS tasusumma
FROM (
    SELECT unnest(xpath('/ns:Document/ns:BkToCstmrStmt/ns:Stmt/ns:Ntry', x, nsa)) as x,
    nsa
    FROM t
) Ntry;
```

I tested this on 10.6; I’m pretty sure it works on 11 too. It also works on previous versions (tested on 9.6).

Comment: 14 hour old question and you beat me to the answer by 5 minutes! Live example: https://rextester.com/ROR68592